# Is there a verb for "thinking someone deserved what he got"?

Tags: verbs, translation

Note that i am not talking about this in the sense of "he deserved what he got", but rather, "i THINK he deserved it".

Basically, when you see someone with a nice car, or when you see a bad person receiving punishment, there is a verb in german and you say: "Ich gönne es ihm" - Literally translated as "I grant it to him" in Deepl, but that doesnt mean the same. It literally means "I think what he has is justified" - it is mostly used in the positive sense when someone who has been through a hard time finally gets something good in life, and you feel happy for him. I was wondering why there is no english word for this, at least i cant find one?

Comment: You can say that someone has *earned* it. It is applicable to non-material things too, such as happiness or recognition. Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/earn) meaning **1.3**.

Comment: There is no verb that I know of, but there is the noun _Schadenfreude_ (stolen, of course, from German) to describe the emotional sensation. Borrowing _gönnen_ would be more difficult, because English doesn't have Dativ, and that's what makes it work in German.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Can we verbify *Schadenfreude*? -> *Schadenfreudise*...

Comment: A typical exclamation for the pejorative case is "**_Justice_**!" Another is a mock statement of monotheistic belief.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a verb, but for a noun "comeuppance" seems to describe what you're after. For verb, may be "requite" or "recompense"? In Chinese there's a simple phrase: "Bao Ying" (报应).

Comment: That works when something bad has happened, but not in the case mentioned where someone has a nice car, which is deserved.